# How to send commands to fbi over SSH?

Tags: ssh, command, fifo, framebuffer, fbi

I'm using `fbi` to display some images. `fbi` has some keyboard controls, like `+`, `-`, `Page Up`, `Page Down`, etc. to control the images.

Instead of using keyboard, I want to send these control commands over SSH to `fbi`.

I have already tried the following method:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mycmd
fbi /myfolder/*.jpg < /tmp/mycmd &
```

After doing so, `fbi` doesn't start. I try sending some commands like `echo . > /tmp/mycmd`, but it doesn't start; and gives the following error:

```
using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)
```

What is the problem?

How can I send commands to `fbi` over SSH !?

Comment: Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

To display an image, `fbi` needs access to the TTY. So, you need to use `-T 1`:

`fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1 zxcv.png`

If you get `access /dev/tty1: Permission denied`, you can run the command with `sudo`.

Unfortunately I don't know of any way of sending commands to it. I tried using [ttyecho](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/) to send things to `/dev/tty1` but it caused `fbi` to crash. Your `fifo` method didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Didn't work for me `sudo fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1  02_06_59.jpg`. It just returned `using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf`

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this too. I changed to virtual terminal 1 and it worked:

```
# Change to virtual terminal 1
chvt 1

# Make a dummy image with ImageMagick if you need one
magick -size 640x480 xc:red image.jpg

# Display on framebuffer
fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1 image.jpg
```

---

In case you are having problems, you can check if `/dev/fb0` is really your frame buffer and you have write permissions with:

```
cat /dev/random > /dev/fb0
```

If your screen gets covered in randomly coloured pixels, you can deduce `/dev/fb0` really is your framebuffer.

If you get a *"Permission denied"* error, try again with:

```
sudo cat /dev/random > /dev/fb0
```

and if that works, change the permissions on `/dev/fb0` with something like:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/fb0
```

---

Or, you can start an elevated bash shell, change permissions and display all in one go:

```
sudo bash -c "chvt 1; fbi -T 1 -d /dev/fb0 image.jpg"
```

---

Or you'll get nothing, in which case you need to ask someone cleverer than me - there are plenty about!

Comment: `sudo cat /dev/random > /dev/fb0` cannot work - the opening of the device is done before sudo gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-d /dev/fb0` option with `fbi`.

By default, `fbi` finds the framebuffer device it's supposed to use by looking at which virtual console device it's being used on. Apparently it looks at its standard input for this purpose. When you're redirecting its standard input from a FIFO, it gets a non-console device and cannot proceed. Specifying the framebuffer device to use explicitly might help.

You might even find that as long as you have the necessary permissions to use the framebuffer device, you even won't need the FIFO: just start `fbi -d /dev/fb0 /myfolder/*.jpg` over the SSH connection, if it suits your purposes.

Comment: Running `fbi -d /dev/fb0 /myfolder/*.jpg` gives exactly the same error: `using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)`